# Parsing of table from .docx file

Tags: python, xml, parsing, docx, python-docx

I want to parse a table from a .docx file using Python and [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) into some useful data structure.

The .docx file contains only a single table in my case. I've [uploaded it so you can have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rhNB.png). Here's a screenshot:

[image: Books.docx]

Comment: Post code and relevant materials here, not on some 3rd party site, and especially not with some shortened URL to some unknown website.

Comment: I have tried a lot of ways to parse it but, didn't get anything to work -- so didn't pasted code. I don't think it is useful if code is not working

Comment: @Cyber I have attached docx file in that link - nothing other than this

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the snippet below to parse your document into a list where each row is a dictionary mapping the table header value to the column value.

```
from docx.api import Document

# Load the first table from your document. In your example file,
# there is only one table, so I just grab the first one.
document = Document('Books.docx')
table = document.tables[0]

# Data will be a list of rows represented as dictionaries
# containing each row's data.
data = []

keys = None
for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
    text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)

    # Establish the mapping based on the first row
    # headers; these will become the keys of our dictionary
    if i == 0:
        keys = tuple(text)
        continue

    # Construct a dictionary for this row, mapping
    # keys to values for this row
    row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))
    data.append(row_data)
```

This will give you:

```
data = [
  {u'Pub.': u'Penguin Books',
   u'Auther': u'Edward de BONO',
   u'Sr. No.': u'1',
   u'Name of Book': u'Six Thinking Hats'
  },
  ...
]
```

If you'd just want a tuple for each row, you should instead of creating a dictionary just set `row_data` to the tuple value of `text`, so in the loop instead of constructing the `dict`, do:

```
# Construct a tuple for this row
row_data = tuple(text)
data.append(row_data)
```

Now, `data` would hold something like this instead:

```
data = [
  (u'1',
   u'Six Thinking Hats',
   u'Edward de BONO',
   u'Penguin Books'
  ),
 ...
]
```

Then you can skip constructing `keys`, obviously (but still skip the first row!).

Comment: in addition to this,if `docx.api` is throwing error then you can use `from docx import Document` directly if the library you installed is `python-docx` instead of `docx`.
Python-docx is compatible with both python2.x and 3.x